# Company Computers all have stuck policies

Tags: group-policy, security-policy

Our company used to be managed by an MSP. We had NO on premise DC/AD but we do use Azure. The problem is somehow, now that the MSP is gone, all the computers have "group policies" for updates etc. 
I have gone through the registry and through RSOP and GPedit and find absolutely nothing configured.
The MSP swears they set no policies via powershell or Intune but yet every computer claims to have policies set.
Any Ideas how this was done and how do I UNDO it?

*update*
I ran a powershell script to find and remove any unlinked GPOs. It reported back that No GPOs are found.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot clearly shows you have group policies enabled though

Answer (score 0):

If the computers are still members of a domain the MSP runs, you'll need to remove them from this domain.

If the MSP has handed control of the domain back to internal staff, you should make sure all the MSP-related accounts are deleted and their privileges removed. You should probably also force all passwords to reset and be changed by their account owners.

If you are removing the domain entirely, you then have to reset any policies applied to the systems by running this command in an elevated command prompt:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
```

This deletes the database containing the policies originating from the domain, and replaces it with the default database.

Comment: Ok so the MSP is gone. They CLAIM they did nothing for group policy. Our DC is Azure with nothing on site.

Comment: Have you run the policy reset script in the answer on the computers and observed the outcome?

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to respond back. this turned out to be a self replicating policy generated from PowerShell. New computers would get their updates from other computers on the network. Slick and powerful piece of scripting, wish I had a copy of it.
It was not intended to be malicious but, the quickest way to get rid of it was a refresh on every system.